# Punishment for thoughts

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory

I was wondering:

1a) Does halacha ever allow for someone to be punished by people (*be'yedei adam*) for a thought the person had? (I'm not sure how *beis din* or whoever would know about the person's thought, but I'm asking anyways).

1b) (a bit of a nuanced question) If the answer to 1a is no: is that because the Torah essentially does not allow for it or is it a pragmatic issue (e.g. not knowing or being able to prove that a person had a certain thought) but  would that it were that we could get around the pragmatic issues a *beis din* would punish?

2) Can a person be punished by God (*be'yedei shamayim*) for a thought the person had even (if no action was performed)?

Comment: 1a) No. 1b) Pragmatic 2) Yes. Source: several gemaras about a thought of Avoda Zarah leading to heavenly punishments, as well as the idea that someone who is mekadesh on condition he is a Rasha Gamur, maybe it is kiddushin because he thought of Avoda Zarah then.

Comment: @yishai I think it's more that the Torah does not allow it _because_ of the pragmatic issue.

Comment: I read in the Jewish Press some time ago that an intention to perform a certain mitzvah (don't remember which one) is sufficient enough even if the mitzvah could not be performed for some reason. I wonder why the opposite wouldn't be true. I am thinking specifically fantasizing about your neighbor's wife, thinking about idol worship, and others

Comment: @JJLL see Moed Katan 18b, Kiddsuhin 39b. There are clearly mitzvos/aveiros of the mind though, see all of sefer Chovos Halevavos

Comment: @Daniel, YeZ in his answer makes a good counter-point from Pigul - there is a fairly case of thought being the underlying problem (at least according to the Rambam and the Chinuch) and lack of punishment being a practical matter.

Answer (score 3):

`1a)` See the Rambam [הלכות סנהדרין והעונשין המסורים להם - פרק שמונה עשר](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02038.html#HtmpReportNum0017_L2)

> **ב**: כָּל לָאו שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ מַעֲשֶׂה אֵין לוֹקִין עָלָיו חוּץ מִנִּשְׁבָּע וּמֵימֵר וּמְקַלֵּל אֶת חֲבֵרוֹ בְּשֵׁם. ‏

**Bet Din would not punish for *non-actions***  with the exception of [false]-oaths, persuading others to transgress and cursing.

So Bet Din would not punish you for your [evil] thoughts - even if all other requirements for punishment were met.

(The first two exceptions obviously require actual talking, and cursing requires one to **say** the name of G-d.)

`1b)` This is a general rule - not related to *not being able to prove it* - since *talking* is considered a *non-action*, yet is easily proven.

`2)` We learn in [Kidushin 39b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01324.html#HtmpReportNum0075_L2) that for thoughts one does not get punished - with the exception of idolatrious thoughts.

> ודלמא מהרהר בעבירה הוה? מחשבה רעה אין הקב''ה מצרפה למעשה! ודלמא מהרהר בעבודת כוכבים הוה *וכתיב {יחזקאל יד-ה} למען תפוש את בית ישראל בלבם*? איהו נמי הכי קאמר... ‏

Comment: I don't think that this is such a good proof to 2b, considering that a lav sheein bo maaseh might be a legal technicality based on drashos (and is in fact a machlokes tannaim)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but not knowing the motivation of your question, maybe this will be helpful to you.  It isn't being punished *directly* for the thought, but a person could be punished as the result of a thought:

The Tiferes Yisroel commentary to Keilim 25:9 writes that both Rashi ([Kiddushin 41b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=41b&format=pdf)) and the Rambam ([Hilchos Pesulei Hamukdashim 18:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/8718.htm#1)) hold that the prohibition of pigul is violated through thought without speech.  So if a person had thoughts of eating a Korban outside of the proper time or place, it then becomes pigul.  If they then ate that Korban, in the right time and place, they would get malkus for eating pigul ([Makkos 13a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=13&format=pdf)).  This would be as a result of their thought.

As an aside, the gemara in [Zevachim 29b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=29&daf=29b&format=pdf) says that according to Rebbi Yehuda, who holds that לאו שאין בו מעשה לוקין עליו (you can get lashes for prohibitions that do not involve an action)([Sh'vuos 3b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=26&daf=3b&format=pdf)), you can get lashes just for the *thought* of eating the Korban in the wrong time or place. So according to this opinion, you could get a Beis Din punishment *directly* for a thought.

Comment: Even according to the Rambam according to Rabbi Yehuda could one get punished even if there is malkus for Lav Shein Bo Maaseh, since there are no witnesses - see the Mishen LeMelech's question in Pesulie HaMukdashim 13:1 || Rashi (Zevachim 41b, DH Kegon and Menachos 2b, DH Aval) seems to require verbal expression.

Comment: @Yishai That's why I cited Tiferes Yisroel - it's a dispute in the correct text of Rashi - the Maharshal took some words out of DH shekein.

Comment: OK, but I'm more interested in the first point though. How do you get around the lack of witnesses (compare with Sahnedrin where it has the same problem with a Navi Sheker and comes up with quite an interesting proposition to address it). Or are you saying that the answer to 1b) is "pragmatic"?